# bootstrap-datepicker validates future dates with "can't be blank" - Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I don't know what's wrong but even I put a future date in my field `:scheduled_date`, rails validates it with *can't be blank*. Actually, the field validates only future dates and blank field but if I put a present date and past dates, there's no problem. Thanks!

---

UPDATED!

This is my model:

registration.rb

```
validates :scheduled_date, presence: true
```

html file:

```
<%=f .label :scheduled_date, 'Date of Appointment:', class: 'control-label' %>
  <div class="datepicker input-group">
    <%=f .text_field :scheduled_date, class: 'form-control', data: { format: "MM/dd/yyyy" } , placeholder: "Select date" %>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
         <span data-date-icon="icon-calendar" class="icon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you post some related code? Your model `validations` and your input for `:scheduled_date` would be very helpful.

Comment: What are sample inputs you given to the `:scheduled_date` field?

Comment: just like 06/25/2014 (that's future date), if I submit, it will validate to can't be blank

Comment: Just a hunch,what happens when you change this line `format: "MM/dd/yyyy"` to `format: "mm/dd/yyyy"`?

Comment: nothing changes. I got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this thing. Actually, the error comes from the `format: "MM/dd/yyyy"` because MySQL only saves for data type date with this format `yyyy/MM/dd`. Thanks!